# JavaScript date formatting for UK dates

Tags: jquery, date

I am sending some strings that represent dates `"dd/mm/yyyy"` to a .net code behind page via an ajax call.

My stripped down code looks like this:

```
var options = new Object();
options.DateStart = '01/01/2013';
options.DateEnd = '01/01/2014';
options.ReviewDate = '23/01/2013';

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        url: "publisher.aspx/SavePage",
        data: JSON.stringify({ options: options }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) { successCallback(data.d, finish.SelectedOption) },
        error: function (data) { failureCallback(data.d) }
    });

  <WebMethod()> _
  <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XMLSerializeString:=False)> _
  Public Shared Function SavePage(ByVal options As PublisherOptions) As PublisherSaveViewModel
```

If the date looks like `'01/01/2013';` then it is fine, if it is `'23/01/2013';` then jQuery throws an internal error. Where do I set it so that it knows im using UK date format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In youre app web config add the following configuration.

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en" />
```

You can also try

```
if ($.validator) {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/mm/yyyy", "en");
        }
    }
```

After the jquery is loaded

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted something a little more scoped to this function. Changing a web config like this will definitely cause some huge issues

Comment: I've also edited the answer for a jquery validator change.
But I've faced the same issue and Chrome just wouldn't work with that.
Only the config solution will work for Chrome.